# Clash between pgf and transparent packages

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, incompatibility, transparent

I get an error with the following MWE when using `pdflatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys, pgfcalendar}
\usepackage{transparent}
\begin{document}
hello world
\end{document}
```

> ```
> ! Undefined control sequence.
>
> \pgfutil@addpdfresource@extgs ...urce@extgs@plain
>
>                                          {#1}
> ```

I can trace it back to `\input pgfutil-common.tex` so it is not really `pgfcalendar` and seems like a general clash with pgf. Is this a bug? If so is it known and is there a work around. If not, which side is it on so I can report it.

Answer (score 10):

I dare say the fault on in PGF's side, sorry if I'm wrong.

The `\pgfutil@addpdfresource@extgs` which shows in the error message seems to be a generic macro which, with the current settings, expands to `\pgf@sys@addpdfresource@extgs@plain`. The latter, however, is undefined. Searching the files for that macro, I found it in driver-specific definition code like `pgfsys-pdftex.def` and the like, which seems like it's not being loaded.

I was going to say that loading `pgfsys-pdftex.def` (or `pgfsys-luatex.def` or `pgfsys-dvipdfmx.def`) manually solves the problem, however loading the driver code when one is using only `pgfrcs` (loaded by `pgfcalendar`, which causes the error) doesn't make much sense, so perhaps the way to go is to un-define `\pgfutil@addpdfresource@extgs`, so that `transparent`'s code won't try to use it:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys, pgfcalendar}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifundefined{pgf@sys@addpdfresource@extgs@plain}%
    {\let\pgfutil@addpdfresource@extgs\SomethingProbablyUndefined}{}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{transparent}
\begin{document}
hello \transparent{0.3}world
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Another way around, instead of loading the driver code manually, would be to load `pgfsys` (and `graphicx`, without which `pgfsys` apparently doesn't work):

```latex
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfkeys, pgfsys, pgfcalendar}
```

Comment: No it is not the fault of pgf but of the compability code in transparent: it tries to detect pgf to coordinate the pdf resources but the test is not quite correct if only a subpart of pgf is loaded. As we are currently working on the management of pdfresources this will stay until a real solution is there. See also https://github.com/ho-tex/oberdiek/issues/62

Comment: @UlrikeFischer so that would be it is known and I should just load more of pgf until things get fixed?

Comment: I think it's strange for pgf to define the generic `\pgfutil@addpdfresource@extgs` in terms of a driver-specific macro which is undefined, but this is just my opinion. However the issue appeared after an update in `transparent.sty`, so...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik yes it is a bit strange, but it is an internal pgf command and it is not pgf's fault if transparent uses such an internal command wrongly.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Putting it like that, indeed it makes sense to be on `transparent`'s side. What if the `\ifcsname` test was done for the inner `\pgf@sys@addpdfresource@extgs@plain`? Apparently there is only one definition for `\pgfutil@addpdfresource@extgs` ([repo search](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/search?q=%22pgfutil%40addpdfresource%40extgs%22&unscoped_q=%22pgfutil%40addpdfresource%40extgs%22)) so perhaps changing the tested macro solves the problem.

Comment: As I wrote we are currently working in the pdfresources management and try to setup things so that tricks as transparent has to use now to coordinate the resources with pgf is no longer needed. This will  mean changes in both packages so I don't see much sense to do some intermediate repairs now.